# Add shading angle to tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I'd like to add a shading angle (like `tikz` nodes: `shading angle=45`) to a `tcolorbox` environment. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{boxed}{enhanced,
    interior style={left color=SpringGreen,right color=Dandelion},frame hidden,width=0.8\textwidth,center,drop shadow}

%\tcbset{boxed/.style={shading angle=120}}


\begin{document}


\begin{boxed}
\lipsum[1]

\end{boxed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

If this is what you want then you just need to add `shading angle=45` to the specifications for `boxed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{boxed}{
    enhanced,
    interior style={left color=SpringGreen,
                    right color=Dandelion,
                    shading angle=45},
    frame hidden,width=0.8\textwidth,center,drop shadow
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{boxed}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{boxed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know it was as easy as in a `tiz` node. I couldn't find this option in the `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: @Joseph I don't think that it is in the `tcolorbox` manual but `tcolorbox` often builds on `tikz` so when in doubt try adding `tikz` styling:)