# Tikz/Graphing in a framed box with shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I am trying to graph a function by using tikz in a framed  box with shadow as in the following links.

[www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/tutorial/demos/tangent.pdf](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/tutorial/demos/tangent.pdf)

I shall be very happy if you can help.

Many thanks for your help.

Barla.

Comment: please add a MWE in the question. links can become invalid.

Comment: What do you mean with MWE?

Comment: @Barla A minimum working example of what you tried so far.

Comment: MWE (Minimal Working Example) is small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem. With it you show what you try so far and where you stuck in your effort and with this help us to help you.

Comment: I am really sorry. I do not have enough knowledge about the tikz.

Comment: @Barla You can also produce a box with the tcolorbox package. Exam https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399327

Answer (score 3):

You should certainly start with looking at the appropriate parts of the comprehensive PGF manual that should be installed on your system (or it can be downloaded from [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)). Reading the short introductions to the libraries `backgrounds` (section 45, p. 571, manual version 3.1.4b) and `shadows` (section 70, p. 768) should be sufficient to achieve the effect described in your original post.

The following simple example presents only one possible way.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadows}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    background rectangle/.style={%
        draw,
        fill=yellow!30,
        general shadow={%
            fill=gray,
            shadow xshift= 1pt,
            shadow yshift=-1pt
            }
        },
    show background rectangle
    ]
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following output...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the shadow I recommend the `shadows.blur` library, for presentations the `beamer` class with the `overlay-beamer-styles` library, to declare the function you want to plot and `decorations.markings` for the tangent.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,overlay-beamer-styles,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some plot}
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.5*(5-(\x-1)*(\x-1));}]
 \draw[thick,fill=yellow!80!gray,blur shadow] (-1.1,-1.1) rectangle (4.1,4.1);
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[below left]{$f(x)$};
 \draw[-stealth] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[below left]{$x$};
 \draw[red,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
 mark=at position 0.5 with {\path (0,0) coordinate (mark);
  \draw[blue,thick,visible on=<3->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);}}}] plot[variable=\x,domain=-0.5:3.5] ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[visible on=<2->] (mark|-0,0.1) -- (mark|-0,-0.1) node[below]{$a$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
 \item Draw the plot.
 \item Mark a position.
 \item Draw the tangent.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Minimal file:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[top color=blue,bottom color=cyan]{(current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west)};
\end{tikzpicture}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
\begin{frame}
Not background
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Place one of the following commands in the **tikzpicture** environment:

```
\fill[top color=blue,bottom color=cyan] {(current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west)};
```

Or

```
\shade[inner color=blue,outer color=red]{(current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west)};
```

Or

```
\shade[left color=blue,right color=cyan]{(current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west)};
```

Comment: @Ahmadi: In my opinion, you are wrong. The asker wants a specific frame around the graphics generated by TikZ. The beamer background is a different issue. Moreover, to change the beamer background, it suffices to call the `\setbeamertemplate`-command and to set the vertical shading. TikZ is rather an overkill in your example.

Comment: Well, I didn't really understand, thanks. Edited